# How to get GraphQL request context using generated schema

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-schema

I needed to grab the authentication header and pass it along on my fetch.  I found a few different ways to do it but wanted access to the context so I can grab it.  All the documentation I saw wasn't related to the typescript way of generating the schema.

So the question is how does someone get a header value within your query/mutations??

Comment: just read docs? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication/#putting-authenticated-user-info-on-the-context

Comment: I found how to access context and how to use it in graphql with a text schema, but I could not find one ounce of documentation explaining that @Ctx was how I query the context values.

Answer (score 0):

So I never found the answer online but decided I should post this in case someone else runs into this issue.

First you need to setup the context that'll be used

```
const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [
        YourResolver
    ]
});

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req }) => {
        // this will return something you can pick up using @Ctx("param")
        const someValue: string = req.headers["some-value"] as string;
        var obj = { 
            value: someValue
        };
        return obj;
    }
});
```

Second you need to reference it

```
@Query(() => string, { nullable: true })
async Get (
    @Ctx("value") val: string
): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((res:any) => { res(value); });
}
```

Works in Query, Mutations, and FieldResolvers.  No param should return the whole object, haven't tested it.